# Возможно ли сделать рендер React приложения на сервере с локальными классами?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack

Есть приложение на react у которого классы генерирует webpack автоматически. 
Встречал такие вещи:

```
if ( process.env.BROWSER ) {
    require('./Footer.less');
}
```

При рендере на сервере это сработает если классы заданы глобальные. Вообщем возможно ли с локальными классами нормально сделать рендер на сервер ?